# Laravel undefined variable in Notification

Tags: laravel

I'm experimenting with laravel and I came across [this](https://medium.com/@sadhakbj/laravel-5-5-activate-account-after-registration-using-laravel-notification-fd5dc7fa05ad) article.
I followed it exactly but for some reason when sending the mail in the Notification class, he can't find the $user variable I declared in the constructor. When printing it in the constructor it works so the user object is passed correctly, but when I want to access it in the toMail method, it's inexisting for some reason. Anyone know why & how to fix this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class UserRegisteredSuccessfully extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->$user = $user;
        // printing here works
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        // ERROR HERE (Undefined variable: user)
        $user = $this->$user;

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Succesfully created new account')
                    ->greeting(sprintf('Hello %s', $user->username))
                    ->line('You have successfully registered to our system. Please activate your account.')
                    ->action('Click here', route('activate.user', $user->activation_code))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Register Method:

```
/**
 * Register new user
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return User
 */
protected function register(Request $request) 
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    try {
        $validatedData['password'] = Hash::make(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));
        $validatedData['activation_code'] = str_random(30).time();
        $user = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        logger()->error($ex);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
    }

    $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made 2 typos:

In your constructor:

```
$this->$user = $user;
```

Should be:

```
$this->user = $user;
```

And in the `toMail()` method:

```
$user = $this->$user;
```

Should be:

```
$user = $this->user;
```

---

The reason it is not working, is because you are currently using the **value** of `$user` as the variable name, and you are not assigning the value of the User object to `$this->user`.

Comment: Wow. I was 200% convinced that it was $this->$user; New to laravel and very long time since I used PHP. Thanks & sorry at the same time!